# when we create a function why we use -(minus) in return in R

Tags: r

when we create a function why we use -(minus) in return, in R program 
see this example

```
f <- function(pars) {
  L <- (n*log(pars[1]))+(n*pars[1]*log(T1))+(n*pars[1]*log(pars[2]))-
       (n*log((T1^pars[1])-(pars[2]^pars[1])))- ((pars[1]+1)*sum(log(pars[2]+x)))
  return(-L)  
}
```

here why we use (-L) in return what if I use return (L)

The sourse of example [Error in f(x, ...) : argument "x" is missing, with no default in nlm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738371/error-in-fx-argument-x-is-missing-with-no-default-in-nlm)

Comment: If you use return(L) then you'll get L instead of -L.  I think you're over thinking this one.

Comment: I confused, Is this mandatory in R to return when my function is L or not because I see a lot of codes used minus when the function has not minus sign

Comment: Usually they do this with the aim of `maximization`. When optimizing functions in R the default set up of the optimizing functions is usually to minimize. A Short cut to this is just to use a `-` sign in the log likelihood function which on being minimized will in turn be maximized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually they do this with the aim of `maximization`. When optimizing functions in R the default set up of the optimizing functions is usually to minimize. A Short cut to this is just to use a `-` sign in the log likelihood function which on being minimized will in turn be maximized. Although not necessary. You can be able to use the controls within the optimizing functions to indicate whether you need to maximize or minimize your log likelihood function

Comment: Is it useful when i use it Bayesian approach or only for classical approach? +1 very thanks

Comment: Any optimization problem can use a negative sign as long as you understand the underlying principles

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you use a minus sign because you a create a function which returns `-L`.  The minus sign is not mandatory in R functions in general:  you could have also written

```
L = -L
return(L)
```

Comment: what is this mean (create a function which returns -L)? This function does not contain minus sign

Comment: @Manal Yes it *does* contain a minus sign. In the previous line of code the value of `L` has become the symmetric of what it was.